# Insert sum into a column in a database using data from a previous row and from current row through a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

Is there any way to create a trigger that automatically calculates the sum and updates the rows in database?
For now i have this query which sums my rows and displays a total.

```
Select
 PreAgg.id,
 PreAgg.debit,
 @PrevBal := @PrevBal + PreAgg.debit As total
From
 (Select
 YT.id,
 YT.debit
From
 test.accounts YT
Order By
 YT.id) As PreAgg,
(Select
@PrevBal := 0.00) As SqlVars
```

This gives me:

```
id debit total

 1  1000  1000
 2  2000  3000
```

My question is how can this be converted into a trigger that calculates the sum after every insert and inserts it into the total field? please give me complete detail and query. thanks.

After doing some research i came up with this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_bal` BEFORE INSERT ON `sp_records` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO ledger
    SELECT
      PreAgg.id,
      PreAgg.tot_amnt,
      @PrevBal := @PrevBal + PreAgg.tot_amnt as balance
   from 
      ( select
              YT.id,
              YT.tot_amnt
           from
              sp_records YT
           order by
              YT.id ) as PreAgg,
      ( select @PrevBal := 0.00 ) as SqlVars
```

But it doesn't let me update my table, says "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" when i insert something in my sp_records table. It works fine though without this trigger.

I have two tables one is sp_records that i want my tot_amnt field from and the other is ledger in which i want to insert the "balance". Both tables have additional fields in addition to the field i have mentioned.

```
CREATE TABLE `ledger` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `debit` float NOT NULL,
 `credit` float NOT NULL,
 `balance` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

heres my ledger.

Comment: Currently only this query. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use formula field on your table. Where you want to show the calculation. The reason why I am suggestion this trigger may drop your SQL engine performance.

(I don’t have enough points to add comments that’s the why I am putting as an answer. )

Cheers.

Comment: i am using mysql. i dont think mysql supports a formula field

Comment: Big pardon. Ignore my comment  i didn't see your tag sorry about that.